# How can I loop an function changing the variable each time it loops until all variables are used?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I want to loop a function changing the variable each time it runs until all variables are used. Currently, I have this function duplicated 20+ times changing out the "a_week" for each one.

```
var a_week = "yes";
var b_week = "no";
var c_week = "yes";

function onload() {
    if a_week = "yes" {
        document.getElementById("dot").classList.add('open');

    }
    else if a_week = "no" {
        document.getElementById("dot").classList.add('closed');

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you please try to expand on your question?

Comment: @AdamH, I have updated the code to simplify what I am doing. I would like to run the function like a loop changing out the variable each loop until all variables are processed. Use a_week, then loop with b_week, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make an array of your weeks, make your `onload` function take an argument and then loop through them.

```
const weeks = [true, false, false, true];

function onload(week) {
  if(week) {
    document.getElementById("dot").classList.add('open');
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dot").classList.add('closed');
  }
}

weeks.forEach(onload);
```

You can look at the docs for `forEach` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach.

For each distinct week, you may not be intending to change the same HTML element each time. The above code would just keep adding classes to the same `#dot` element. If you intended to target multiple elements, maybe save an array of elements or their selectors. Or combine that with the data in an object like my old answer has. You didn't share your HTML structure so I'm not sure what the best way to structure the DOM manipulation is.

Also `onload` is not a great name for a function since it may be assumed to be connected to the browser's [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event.

---

## Answer for old question:

Seems like you should make whatever `sa_g_week` represents an object and then loop through an array of them (or make  an map/object out of them if they need to be referenced by key). I'm not sure what your context is but I'm going to make up some field names and assume you're working with locations.

```
const locations = [
    {
        isOpen247: true,
        isPermanentlyClosed: false,
        openTime: new Date(),
        closeTime: new Date(),
    },
    {
        isOpen247: true,
        isPermanentlyClosed: true,
        openTime: new Date(),
        closeTime: new Date(),
    },
];
```

You could then loop through the array and do what you need to:

```
locations.forEach(location => {
  if(location.isOpen247) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    // do other stuff
  }
});
```